I am trying to write a program in Rust for Solana, but I encounter a problem when using the macro #[entrypoint]
I am trying to write a program in Rust for Solana, but I encounter a problem when using the macro #[entrypoint]. Here is my code:
// src/lib.rs
use solana_program::entrypoint;
use solana_program::{
account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
entrypoint::ProgramResult,
program_error::ProgramError,
pubkey::Pubkey,
};
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
#[entrypoint]
fn process_instruction(program_id: &Pubkey, accounts: &[AccountInfo], instruction_data: &[u8]) -> ProgramResult {
let instruction: TokenInstruction = TokenInstruction::try_from_slice(instruction_data)
.map_err(|_| ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)?;
// ... the rest of the code ...

}
// Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "token"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
[dependencies]
solana-program = "1.18.11"
borsh = "1.4.0"
serde = "1.0.198"
bincode = "1.3.3"
pyo3 = "0.21.2"
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
When I try to build a project using cargo build, I get the following error:
error: cannot find attribute entrypoint in this scope
--> src/lib.rs:43:3
|
43 | #[entrypoint]
|   ^^^^^^^^^^
|
note: entrypoint is imported here, but it is a function-like macro
--> src/lib.rs:1:5
|
1  | use solana_program::entrypoint;
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Rust version 1.68.0
Solana version 1.18.11
macOS Ventura 13.3.1

I would be grateful for any help or recommendations to solve this problem.

The entrypoint is usually called at the end as:
entrypoint!(process_instruction);

after the process_instruction()
Shouldn't add entrypoint as an attribute #[]
